# Swift compiling error: Module map file not found + Missing required module 'SwiftShims'

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, swiftcharts

I keep getting these errors after mistakenly running pod update.
Spent the last couple of days searching for solution but nothing helped, some of my attemtps:

1) [How to fix cocoapod .modulemap file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55675694/how-to-fix-cocoapod-modulemap-file-not-found)

2) [missing required module 'SwiftShims' error generated by Xcode in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849335/missing-required-module-swiftshims-error-generated-by-xcode-in-project)

Tried all the mentioned solutions in these Q's and some other SO Q's and nothing helped.

Error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo- 
dkfcfedygluokngempogitocknga/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Charts/Charts.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo- 
dkfcfedygluokngempogitocknga/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Charts/Charts.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: missing required module 'SwiftShims'
```

This is my Podfile:

```
target "Demo" do
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionTextModel'
pod 'Charts', '3.2.0'
end
```

I'm running MacOS 10.13.6 with Xcode 10.1, Cocoa pods version is 1.7.1

Answer (score 2):

I had the error while trying to compile from the .xcodeproj instead of the .xcworkspace

(Building a React Native with Okta)

Comment: Wow. It works. Idk how, but that doesn't matter lol.