# xcode 11 - missing required module '_SwiftCoreMediaOverlayShims'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

While running on real device, I am getting this error

> :0: error: missing required module '_SwiftCoreMediaOverlayShims'

Xcode version: 11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [missing required module 'SwiftShims' error generated by Xcode in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849335/missing-required-module-swiftshims-error-generated-by-xcode-in-project)

Comment: No didn't help, I posted the answer below. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem related to third-party library which is not supporting iOS 10. So when I updated the project to support starting from iOS 11.0 it works.